# How to unpack values from a file

Tags: python, arrays, adjacency-list

If as a input i have a file that read-

```
0->54:15
1->41:12
2->35:6
3->42:10
4->34:7
5->58:5
6->55:12
7->39:6
8->36:12
9->38:15
10->53:13
11->56:12
12->51:5
13->48:8
14->60:14
15->46:12
16->57:6
17->52:9
18->40:11
```

Actually this is an adjacency list. I want my code to read the file and take the values as -> u=0,v=54, w=15 and then go with my plan. How can i do this? Thank you in advance for your time to read and answer this.

Comment: Why not just use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or JSON instead of trying to roll your own serialization?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can read each line as a string and then use `.split()` to get the data that you need.

Comment: There are (-> , :) signs..how to handle with with these while using split function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a single string:

```
import re

s = \
'''0->54:15
1->41:12
2->35:6
3->42:10
4->34:7
5->58:5
6->55:12
7->39:6
8->36:12
9->38:15
10->53:13
11->56:12
12->51:5
13->48:8
14->60:14
15->46:12
16->57:6
17->52:9
18->40:11'''

s = s.split('\n')
output = [re.split('->|:', x) for x in s]
```

output

```
[['0', '54', '15'], ['1', '41', '12'], ['2', '35', '6'], ['3', '42', '10'], ['4', '34', '7'], ['5', '58', '5'], ['6', '55', '12'], ['7', '39', '6'], ['8', '36', '12'], ['9', '38', '15'], ['10', '53', '13'], ['11', '56', '12'], ['12', '51', '5'], ['13', '48', '8'], ['14', '60', '14'], ['15', '46', '12'], ['16', '57', '6'], ['17', '52', '9'], ['18', '40', '11']]
```

If you want a dictionary

```
d = {x[0]:[x[1],x[2]] for x in output}
```

d

```
{'0': ['54', '15'], '1': ['41', '12'], '2': ['35', '6'], '3': ['42', '10'], '4': ['34', '7'], '5': ['58', '5'], '6': ['55', '12'], '7': ['39', '6'], '8': ['36', '12'], '9': ['38', '15'], '10': ['53', '13'], '11': ['56', '12'], '12': ['51', '5'], '13': ['48', '8'], '14': ['60', '14'], '15': ['46', '12'], '16': ['57', '6'], '17': ['52', '9'], '18': ['40', '11']}
```

If you want a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=['u','v','w'])
```

df

```
     u   v   w
0    0  54  15
1    1  41  12
2    2  35   6
3    3  42  10
4    4  34   7
5    5  58   5
6    6  55  12
7    7  39   6
8    8  36  12
9    9  38  15
10  10  53  13
11  11  56  12
12  12  51   5
13  13  48   8
14  14  60  14
15  15  46  12
16  16  57   6
17  17  52   9
18  18  40  11
```

Comment: Is there any way to get a dictionary? {0:{54:15},1:{41:12}....} something like this?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have learnt a lot more than i wanted from you :)

Answer (score 3):

Using .split would be good.
For each line in the file (You can get this by using the `open()` function) split it using the arrow and the colon.

```
for line in lines:
    split_line = line.split("->") # Split by the arrow first
    split_line = split_line[0] + split_line[1].split(":")
    u, v, w = split_line # Note u, v, and w are strings
```

I would recommend using JSON format so you can use the json module in python the parse the file into variables easily.

Comment: why not unpack in each split instead of afterward? `[u, rest] = line.split("->") ; [v,w] = rest.split(":")`

Comment: Yeah you can do that too. That might be better and look cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use `re.split()` to split strings with multiple delimiters:

```
from re import split

with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    l = f.read().splitlines()

lst = [list(filter(None, split('[(\-\>):]',s))) for s in l]

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[['0', '54', '15'],
 ['1', '41', '12'],
 ['2', '35', '6'],
 ['3', '42', '10'],
 ['4', '34', '7'],
 ['5', '58', '5'],
 ['6', '55', '12'],
 ['7', '39', '6'],
 ['8', '36', '12'],
 ['9', '38', '15'],
 ['10', '53', '13'],
 ['11', '56', '12'],
 ['12', '51', '5'],
 ['13', '48', '8'],
 ['14', '60', '14'],
 ['15', '46', '12'],
 ['16', '57', '6'],
 ['17', '52', '9'],
 ['18', '40', '11']]
```

---

---

Breaking it down:

This: `lst = [list(filter(None, split('[(\-\>):]',s))) for s in l]` is the equivalent of:

```
lst = [] # The main list
for s in l: # For every line in the list of lines
    uvw = split('[(\-\>):]',s) # uvw = a list of the numbers
    uvw = list(filter(None,uvw)) # There is an empty string in the list, so filter it out
    lst.append(uvw) # Add the list to the main list
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to challenge the way that you're getting the input file in the first place: if you have any control over how you get this input, I'd encourage you to change its format. (If not, maybe this answer will help people who have a similar issue in the future).

There is typically little reason to "roll your own" serialization and deserialization like this - it's reinventing the wheel, given that most modern languages have built-in libraries to do this already. Rather, if at all possible, you should use a standard serialization and deserialization mechanism like [Python pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or a JSON serializer (or even a CSV, so that you can use a CSV parser).

Comment: Actually, coding exercises of bioinformatics courses under Coursera give dataset in a txt format to solve and the dataset is generally too large to copy-paste. And there is time limit also (from getting the dataset to submitting). That's why i can't help reading the file directly from my code and looking out for the output. I wasn't sure if there would be solution and couldn't know it is super easy with built in modules without your variety of answers. :)